# Python argument types in rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToMolBlock(NoneType)

Tags: python, rdkit

I am trying to convert inchi to sdf format using rdkit python library. I am running following line of python code.

```
#convert inchi to sdf

def MolFromInchi(id,inchi):
    mol = Chem.MolFromInchi(inchi)
    mol_block = Chem.MolToMolBlock(mol)
    print (id, mol_block)
    print ('$$$$')
    
with open (r'C:/Users/inchi_canonize') as f:                                                                                   
    for line in f:
        lst=line.split(' ')
        elements = [x for x in lst if x]   #remove empty elements and get id (elements[0]) and inchis (elements[1])
        elements[1] = ('\''+elements[1].strip()+'\'')
        id = elements[0]
        inchi = elements[1].rstrip("\n")
        print (inchi)
        MolFromInchi(id,inchi)
```

The input file (inchi_canonize) has following fields.

```
D08520   InChI=1S/C10H18O2/c1-7-4-5-8(6-9(7)11)10(2,3)12/h4,8-9,11-12H,5-6H2,1-3H3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
D07548   InChI=1S/C17H25NO4.ClH/c1-20-13-11-15(21-2)17(16(12-13)22-3)14(19)7-6-10-18-8-4-5-9-18;/h11-12H,4-10H2,1-3H3;1H                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
D10000   (null)
```

Below is the error:

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToMolBlock(NoneType)
did not match C++ signature:
    MolToMolBlock(class RDKit::ROMol mol, bool includeStereo=True, int confId=-1, bool kekulize=True, bool forceV3000=False)
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `elements[1] = ('\''+elements[1].strip()+'\'')`.

The InChI is already a string and you add `'" "'` to it.

Your InChI is now `"'InChI=1S/C10H18O2/c1-7-4-5-8(6-9(7)11)10(2,3)12/h4,8-9,11-12H,5-6H2,1-3H3'"`

and not `InChI=1S/C10H18O2/c1-7-4-5-8(6-9(7)11)10(2,3)12/h4,8-9,11-12H,5-6H2,1-3H3`.

Additionally you should insert a check, because otherwise you try to convert also `(null)` to a molblock.

And by the way, you can use `Chem.SDWriter` for writting a SDF.

```
from rdkit import Chem

mols = []
ids = []
inchis = []

with open(r'D:\Z\inchi_canonize.txt') as f:                                                                                   
    for line in f:
        lst=line.split(' ')
        elements = [x for x in lst if x]
        inchi = elements[1].rstrip("\n")
        mol = Chem.MolFromInchi(inchi)
        if mol is not None:
            mols.append(mol)
            ids.append(elements[0])
            inchis.append(inchi)

w = Chem.SDWriter('foo.sdf')

for n in range(len(mols)):
    mols[n].SetProp('_Name', inchis[n]) # set a title line
    mols[n].SetProp('ID', ids[n] ) # set an associated data
    w.write(mols[n])

w.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Could you explain what below line is doing.                                                           for n in range(len(mols)):
    mols[n].SetProp('_Name', idx[n])
    w.write(mols[n])

Comment: This line writes every molecule into foo.sdf and makes ID and Inchi the title line for every entry.

Comment: Is there a way to add a property before the end of a particular entry. for eg.                   `                                                                                                                                    > <ID>                                                                                                                         D08520                                                                                                                                `

Comment: @rshar I edited the code, so the ID is now an associated data and only the InChI is in the title line.